# I made a Swift extension to use frames like I would on iOS but Can't compile while using it

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I made this extension to NSView to make it easier to work with views.

```
import Cocoa

public extension NSView {
    var invertedFrame: NSRect {
    get {
        return NSRect(x: frame.origin.x,
                      y: superview.bounds.height - frame.origin.y,
                  width: bounds.size.width,
                 height: bounds.size.height)
    }
    set {

        self.frame = NSRect(x: newValue.origin.x,
                            y: superview.bounds.height - newValue.origin.y - newValue.height,
                        width: newValue.width,
                       height: newValue.height)
    }
    }
}
```

But whenever I try to use it I get the compile time error ...

```
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

However if I cut and paste the computed variable into a class implementation it works fine.

I am not sure why this is.  Is there something wrong with my code?  Can anyone make this work?

Comment: full error message? and [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com/) because compile cannot crash

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear but I am using this extension for Mac OSX apps in order to make the coordinate system work like it does on iOS

Comment: Have you Cleaned & Built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which update fixed this, but in Xcode 6 beta 5 it works fine.  So it was just a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your property setter doesn't declare `newValue` as a method parameter, but instead of telling you that, the compiler is clearly crashing. Remember that a bare `set` is found only in a `protocol` property declaration.

Comment: newValue is the name given automatically if you don't specify it as a parameter.

Comment: Well, I'll be damned. TIL. Thanks.